# Flask + Sqlite3 incorrect formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlite

I am building a website where people can apply for the team, it's been going well so far however when I display the applications on a page, this shows up.

`(' IGN:\r\n Age:\r\n Server Proxy:\r\n Nationality:\r\n TeamSpeak?:\r\n Discord?:\r\n Twitter?:\r\n YouTube?:\r\n Requirement Option:\r\n Exceptions:\r\n Current Clans?:\r\n Why Ominous?:\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t',)`

The textarea looks like this,

```
                </header>
                    <h1>Enter Application</h1>
                <form action="/memberapp" method="POST">
                    <textarea type="text" name="text" size="350" rows="13">
IGN:
Age:
Server Proxy:
Nationality:
TeamSpeak?:
Discord?:
Twitter?:
YouTube?:
Requirement Option:
Exceptions:
Current Clans?:
Why Ominous?:
                    </textarea>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Submit">
```

The way I am inserting the data looks like this:

```
text = request.form['text']
connect()
conn = sqlite3.connect("main.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO memberapps VALUES(?)", (text,))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
conn = sqlite3.connect("main.db")
```

That isn't the issue however, finally, the way I am displaying it is like so:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("main.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM memberapps")
r = c.fetchall()
conn.close()
return render_template('member-view.html', rows=r)
```

`{% for r in rows %}
    <h2>{{r}}</h2>
{% endfor %}`

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean? like the tabs @roganjosh

Comment: @roganjosh I made it like that because otherwise it looks like this

Comment: https://gyazo.com/71171dc8d1a423ebb7e4346094f2d937

Comment: UPDATE: By making it rows[0] I was able to get this, `IGN: Age: Server Proxy: Nationality: TeamSpeak?: Discord?: Twitter?: YouTube?: Requirement Option: Exceptions: Current Clans?: Why Ominous?:` It still isn't on a new line each time though.

Comment: Nah, br don't work in textareas ty tho

Comment: Tried a bunch of things, nothing working.

Comment: Question: Why a text area? If all the fields are there, why not make individual textboxes?

Comment: @Willy_Sunny Yeah, that's what I ended up doing, looks better anyways.