# Flask + Sqlite3 incorrect string formatting

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have same problem like this: [Flask + Sqlite3 incorrect formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779416/flask-sqlite3-incorrect-formatting)

I have homework to make note taking website. I can add the note, it saves into the database and I can receive it and print it but the formating is wrong.

This is what I get after recieving the note from 1st image:
('This is line 1\r\n\r\nThis is line 3\r\nThis is line 4',)

and if I convert it to string str(note) or just note[0] it looks like on 2nd image..without the new lines

[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOA9D.png)

[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0PYJ.png)

I tried to search for it everywhere but I just can't make it work.

```
`https://pastebin.com/Mrcxb9mq
@app.route('/notes')
def showNotes():
    """Zobrazí všechny poznamky."""
    conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(curDir,'notes.db'))
    c = conn.cursor()
    notes = c.execute("SELECT rowid, body, kdy FROM note").fetchall()
    #note = c.execute(f"SELECT body FROM note").fetchone()
    conn.close()
    return render_template('showNotes.html', notes=notes)`
```

Comment: You need to show the code of how you're generating the output and we can help.

Comment: @v25 there it is

Comment: What is happening in showNotes.html? If i understand you correctly you want to show the notes one after the other with lines?